# Set invalid input when it has emojis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set an input as invalid if it contains any emoji (aka emoticons) with a directive.

> I'm using the following code: http://codepen.io/fuxes/pen/JYJNKW use  to start playing.

If I try to use a name such as  it works fine, it detects that it has emojis. But the weird thing is that if I start to add any letter, it starts to break!

I'll do the following:
`asd` -> Emojis where detected
`asdds` -> Emojis where NOT detected
`asdd` -> Emojis where detected
`asdds` -> Emojis where detected

Note that 2 and 4 are equals. I don't understand why this behavior happens. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change:

```
!hasEmojis.test(value)
```

to:

```
!value.match(hasEmojis)
```

I guess something is wrong with your regex or the way you use it, try to first cut it down to 1 or 2 symbols and figure it out and then see if the test method work, or, use the modification I suggested.

Comment: It works! Could you please explain, why is this change necessary?

Comment: Not sure what breaks there. But for some reason your test(value) fails. .match(...) returns the matched parts and for some reason works.